# Python 3.x -> Find Last Occurrence of character in string by using recursion and loop

Tags: python

Could someone teach me how to find the last occurrence of a character in string by using recursion/loop instead of build-in function?

I figured out the loop-method(below), but have no clue about recursion...

```
def find_last(line,ch):
    if line == None or len(line)==0:
        return -1

    else:
        found_at = 0
        index= 0
        for ch_line in line:
            if ch_line == ch:
                found_at = index
            index+=1
        return found_at

print(find_last("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "g"))
```

> > > returns 42

Many thanks from a python beginner!!

Comment: `return line.rfind(ch)`?

Comment: It should work. But what if using loop and recursion. Sorry for the stupid question, it is only because I need to practice them:( Thank you in any case!!!

Comment: @SuwanWang I suggest you tried to implement it yourself, if get stuck, comeback and ask a question.

Comment: I tried for ca 1 hour...but you are right! Thank you!!

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SuwanWang what should happen if the character is not found? What should the function return?

Comment: @Prune Thank you:) I figured out the loop-Method this morning!

Comment: @YakovDan Thank you for your help! I just figured out the loop-method and have edited the post, now working on recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iteration:

```
def find_last(line,ch):
    last_seen =-1
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i] == ch:
            last_seen=i
    return last_seen
```

With recursion:

```
def find_last_rec(line,ch,count):
    if count==line(len)-1:
        return -1
    elif line[count] ==ch:
        return max(count, find_last_rec(line,ch,count+1))
    else:
        return find_last_rec(line,ch,count+1)


def find_last(line,ch):
    return find_last_rec(line,ch,0)
```